# Убрать 1-букву из message.text

Tags: python, telegram, sqlite3

есть бот, юзер отправить например message.text='dkoshka'
мне надо чтобы message.text выглядела 'koshka'.
Пробовали сначала message.text=list(message.text) и message.text=message.text[1:]. не помогает.
Мне надо будет передать в запрос:
result_query = cur.execute("SELECT ostatki_tovara, nazvanie_tovara  FROM  tovarniye_ostatki_oboy WHERE nazvanie_tovara MATCH (?)",(message.text.lower(),))

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def message_handler(message):
message.text=message.text[1:]
if message.text in shop1:
    send_docs(message)
elif message.text=='d':
     send_docs_oboy(message)
elif message.text in shop2:
    send_docs_shop2(message)
elif message.text in shop3:
    send_docs_shop3(message)
elif message.text in shop4:
    send_docs_shop4(message)
elif message.text not in (shop1 and shop2 and shop3 and shop4):
    send_query(message)
elif message.text not in (shop1 and shop2 and shop3 and shop4 and                   
                                                  message.text.startswith('s'):
    send_query_shop2(message) 
elif message.text not in (shop1 and shop2 and shop3 and shop4 and 
                                                  message.text.startswith('y')):
    send_query_shop3(message)
elif message.text not in (shop1 and shop2 and shop3 and shop4 and 
                                                   message.text.startswith('g')):
    send_query_shop4(message.text)

elif message.text not in (shop1 and shop2 and shop3 and shop4 and 
                                                   message.text.startswith('d')):
    send_docs_oboy(message)
```

Comment: 99,9% что строчка ``elif message.text not in (shop1 and shop2 and shop3 and shop4)`` и все аналогичные делают совсем не то, что вам кажется.

Comment: ``message.text=message.text[1:]`` это именно то, что вам нужно, и оно, конечно же, помогает. Проблема у вас совсем в другом. Именно в тех самых условиях.